# FISH error upon startup to access a file that does exist

Tags: fish

On an Ubuntu 14.04, I have started to receive the following warning (or error) each time I start a new session in terminal :

```
Unable to make or open a FIFO for universal variables with path '/run/user/0/fishd.12c79b706e7a.notifier': Permission denied
```

When I try to look into this file, the file does not exist at all.

Comment: fish is trying to make a FIFO in $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR, but that appears to be root's runtime directory. Are you logged in as root? What does `echo $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` show?

Comment: Thanks. I'm not logged in as root. It gives me `/run/user/0`. and `sudo ls -lart /run/user/0` gives `total 0
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 60 Dec 23 10:03 ..
drwx------ 2 root root 40 Dec 23 10:03 .`

Comment: It looks like something is misconfigured about your system. From the [XDG spec](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html): "The directory MUST be owned by the user, and he MUST be the only one having read and write access to it. Its Unix access mode MUST be 0700." That's not the case for your system. I suppose we ought to work around this in fish.

Comment: Just wanted to note that I also see this error on Windows with Cygwin.  Restarting the console window as administrator fixed the problem, although maybe I need to alter some permissions on the config folder/files manually for a better and more permanent solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [fish issue #2222](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/2222).

The problem seems to be that you get the wrong value for $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR. In that issue the reporter said `su -l` caused it, which, unlike what the documentation said, did *not* clear $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR or set it again to the wrong value.

I get a much more benign issue on fish 2.2.0 (and current git):

> fish: No TTY for interactive shell (tcgetpgrp failed)
>
> setpgid: Inappropriate ioctl for device

which seems not to break anything, so I can only recommend upgrading.

Comment: That it doesn't break as bad anymore is probably caused by abandoning fishd (which was a daemon used to sync universal variables) in 2.2.0.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem setting my terminal to fish in IntelliJ IDEA on Manjaro.

Every time I opened up the terminal, it kept printing the following error message;

```
Unable to open universal variable file '/opt/intellij-idea-ultimate-edition/plugins/terminal/fish/fish_variables': Permission denied
```

The solution I used, while not ideal did stop the error message - it's trying to write to a root controlled location from user land. from the terminal type the following command:

```
chown -R USER:USER /opt/intellij-idea-ultimate-edition/plugins/terminal/fish
```